# Is it possible to have multiple AsyncTask in different activities for posting data to server(Android)?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using 2 AsyncTask in 2 different activities for posting data to different URL's in my android app.But however only datas of first AsyncTask  is getting posted to server.But 2nd  AsyncTask data are getting stored to namevalue pairs as I can see it in my Log,But not getting posted to server.Can any one help with the issue?

Thanks in advance.

This is my first AsyncTask

```
private class PostData extends AsyncTask<String, String, HttpResponse> {
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://application.easypani.com/app/customer/register");

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        // Add your data
        Name = full_name.getText().toString();
        Phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();
        Email = email.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        House = house.getText().toString();
        Street = street.getText().toString();
        Landmark = landmark.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", Name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", Phonenumber));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("house", House));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area", Area));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("street", Street));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("landmark", Landmark));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.e("post_", nameValuePairs.toString());
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return response;
}
```

}

This is my second AyncTask in another activity

```
 private class PostOrder extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpResponse> {
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost1 = new HttpPost("http://application.easypani.com/app/customer/order");

        HttpResponse response1 = null;
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("suppliername", SupplierName));
            nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", Quantity));
            nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newdispenser", dispenserchecked));
            nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newconnection", newconnectionchecked));
            httppost1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs1));
            Log.e("post_order", nameValuePairs1.toString());
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response1 = httpclient1.execute(httppost1);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return response1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to create a separate java class of type AsyncTask with HttpPost as input and then call it every time you need.

Comment: Sorry I am new to android..can you show me  how to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: After registering from first Async class are you getting any response???? Is your application need to have a session???

Comment: Yes I am getting response from first Async class..My application doesn't need a session..I am just saving the details to cache using sharedpreference.

Comment: `public class PostData extends AsyncTask<HttpPost, String, HttpResponse> {
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(HttpPost...arg0) {
        ...response = httpclient.execute(arg0[0]);...
    }
}`

Comment: I have just checked you second api call and in response it sending data so definitely there is something wrong in your second async class.

Comment: I guess your backend code is not correct i have checked it on AdvanceRestClient plugin from browser. I am getting response 200 OK with some data which i have not posted but still i am getting the values.

Comment: Use **Postman** or **AdvanceRestClient** plugin for chrome chrome browser so you will get an idea what is wrong happening.

Comment: Nothing wrong is showing in Postman..I am able to get some hardcoded values entered but not able to store the values from asynctask.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating AsyncTask in each activity, create a separate AsyncTask class which can be called from any activity or fragments.
Here I have written one separate class for AsyncTask and the response will reach the activity through an interface.

[Click here to get the samples from drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ZvrlZMOz4hTVhJRkVoNERhMjQ)

Implement the interface in your activity or fragment and override the method to get the response from your server in your activity or fragment.

As the HttpClient is not supported anymore in SDK 23, you need to import the *org.apache.http.legacy.jar*  (included in the drive) file in your libs folder.

But instead of using AsyncTask, you can use **Google Volley**.

Volley provides

- Multiple concurrent network connections.
- Automatic scheduling of network requests.
- Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP cache coherence.
- Request prioritization.
- Cancelation request API.
- Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with data fetched asynchronously from the network.

[Volley Android Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
[Introduction to Volley](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)
[Volley Example Code](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)